# AWS Lambda cannot find module using a local sam deploy

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

So I created a small project in typescript that I want to test locally before deploying to aws cloud. I wanted to use aws sam. I have installed the sam cli. For this I have the following template.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: A simple AWS Lambda function with API Gateway integration.

Resources:
  CompanyActivityFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: dist/handlers/srl/company_order/
      Handler: companyOrderHandler.beginCompanyOrderHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Timeout: 10
      Events:
        CreateActivity:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /company-order/create
            Method: POST
```

My tsconfig.json is the follwing

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2020",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "CommonJS",                                  /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    
    /* Emit */
    "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    "outDir": "dist",                                    /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "preserveConstEnums": true,                          /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                    /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

I ran `sam local start-api` there were no issue but then I made a call to the endpoint and got the following error

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '../../../util/gatewayEventUtil'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/companyOrderHandler.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "stack": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '../../../util/gatewayEventUtil'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/companyOrderHandler.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:997:17)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1195:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1201:1"
  ]
}
```

Now the error seemed very intuitive but the issue happened when checking the code for `companyOrderHandler.js`

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.updateCompanyWithExistingCompanyAddress = exports.updateCompanyWithNewCompanyAddress = exports.beginCompanyOrderHandler = void 0;
const awsGatewayEventUtil = __importStar(require("../../../util/gatewayEventUtil"));
const companyOrderService = __importStar(require("../../../services/company/create/companyOrderService"));
const beginCompanyOrderHandler = async (companyOrderCreateEvent) => {
...
```

The problem is the location for awsGatewayEventUtil is correct
I checked it myself, visual studio code says it is good, at the location there exists a file gatewayEventUtil.js.

Is there anything that I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

PS: If there is any other information that is needed please let me know

Comment: "location for awsGatewayEventUtil is correct I checked it myself" `../../../` is relative to the current working directory.  Maybe the local api invocation doesn't have the current working directory you expect?  If you can find the PID of the server you can get its current working directory inside `/proc/$PID`

Comment: @erik258 is there a PID even if the process is running in docker? maybe it is a dumb question but I never thought about it

Comment: not a dumb question at all.  Absolutely there's a PID.  Docker is a containerization technology; it uses namespacing to isolate docker containers from the rest of the system.  Within the docker host, all the docker containers' apps are running as processes, but they don't see the whole docker host.

Comment: @erik258 So I did something a bit more of a cheat. I created a new endpoint that only returns as response the process.cwd() and it returned var/task. is that equivalent to what your suggestion was?